# Django how to customize upload_to function

Tags: python, django

I created a system with Django. In this system **a user** has more than one customers. There is a customer list. A user can upload files to **a customer's page**. What I want to is the file should save in a file and path of this file should be `customer_customername`  (For example: customer_Emily). But in my code created a file that name as `customer_None`. How can i fix it? file upload model and customer model are 2 different models that connecetd with a foreign key `owner`

**Pdf/models.py**

```
def customer_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'customer_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.id, filename)


class Pdf(models.Model):
    CHOICES = [
        ...
    ]

    STAT = [
        ...

    ]

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to=customer_directory_path)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

**customer/models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    ...

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
```

**views.py**

```
def pdf_list(request,id):
    customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=id)
    pdfs = Pdf.objects.filter(owner=customer)
    return render(request, 'pdf_list.html', {'pdfs': pdfs})
def upload_pdf(request,id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        customer = get_object_or_404(Customer, id=id)
        form = PdfForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_pdf=form.save()
            new_pdf.owner = customer
            new_pdf.save()
            return redirect('pdf_list',id)
    else:
        form = PdfForm()

    return render(request, 'upload_pdf.html', {'form': form})
```

**forms.py**

```
class PdfForm(forms.ModelForm):
    INTEGER_CHOICES = [tuple([year, year]) for year in range(2015, datetime.now().year + 1)]
    year = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.Select(choices=INTEGER_CHOICES))


    class Meta:
        model = Pdf
        fields = ['title', 'pdf', 'type', 'year']
```

Note: When I change `.format(instance.id, filename)` as `.format(instance.owner.customer_name, filename)` there is an error:

> AttributeError at /pdfs/analyses/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute
> 'customer_name'

**traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pdfs/12/upload/

Django Version: 3.1.4
Python Version: 3.8.7
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'register',
 'customer',
 'financial_analysis',
 'ocr',
 'crispy_forms',
 'ckeditor']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 179, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\financial_analysis\views.py", line 24, in upload_pdf
        new_pdf=form.save()
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py", line 460, in save
        self.instance.save()
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 753, in save
        self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 790, in save_base
        updated = self._save_table(
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 895, in _save_table
        results = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, returning_fields, raw)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 933, in _do_insert
        return manager._insert(
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
        return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1254, in _insert
        return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1396, in execute_sql
        for sql, params in self.as_sql():
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1339, in as_sql
        value_rows = [
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
        [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1340, in <listcomp>
        [self.prepare_value(field, self.pre_save_val(field, obj)) for field in fields]
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1291, in pre_save_val
        return field.pre_save(obj, add=True)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 307, in pre_save
        file.save(file.name, file.file, save=False)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 86, in save
        name = self.field.generate_filename(self.instance, name)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\myvenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\files.py", line 322, in generate_filename
        filename = self.upload_to(instance, filename)
      File "C:\Users\USER\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\otc\financial_analysis\models.py", line 10, in customer_directory_path
        return 'customer_{0}/{1}'.format(self.owner.customer_name, filename)
    
    Exception Type: AttributeError at /pdfs/12/upload/
    Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'customer_name'
```

Comment: `instance.id` would be none as the `customer_directory_path` is invoked before generating a pk

Comment: @MjZac What should I do? Please help me

Comment: did you try `return 'customer_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.owner.customer_name, filename)`?

Comment: @ItsMilann It shows an error: AttributeError at /pdfs/analyses/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'customer_name'

Comment: @stephone How are you using `Pdf` object? in your `views.py`? Can you post the code of the usage as well?

Comment: @MjZac I added view.py

Comment: @stephone Can you post the code for pdf upload ?

Comment: @Conans I added upload_pdf

Comment: @stephone can you add `PdfForm` also?

Comment: Also make sure you post error stack trace.

Comment: @MjZac I added pdf form and traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
new_pdf = form.save()
```

To this:

```
new_pdf = form.save(commit=False)
```

As you have not provided the owner then to the model object, you should not commit the object there. After specifying the owner, the owner will not be `None` any longer, therefore the code will work as intended.